# ListView in Scenebuilder not showing (Java FX Eclipse IDE)

Tags: java, eclipse, listview, javafx, scenebuilder

So I am trying to add a item in AddListController.java that is connected to addList.fxml, and then transfer that added item into my ListView in my MyListEducationController in my MyList_Education.fxml. The thing is, the console showed that the item is added, but my ListView is still empty. I am also using a DataModel class to connect the two.

handleAddListButton clicked
Title:  testing one two three
DataModel contents: [ testing one two three]
updateListView method called
Items in DataModel: [ testing one two three]
ListView items set: [ testing one two three]

These are my following codes

[MyListEducationController]

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import application.DataModel;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MyListEducationController implements Initializable{
    
    


    @FXML
    private ListView<String> listView;
    private DataModel dataModel;
    
    
        @FXML
        private Button addListButton;
        @FXML
        private Button homeButton;
        @FXML
        private Button myListButton;
        @FXML
        private Button profileButton;
        @FXML
        private Scene myListScene;
        @FXML
        private Main mainController;

        
        @FXML
        private Button eduDoneList;
        
        public DataModel getDataModel() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return dataModel;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (listView != null) {
                listView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList()); 
            }
        }

        
        public ListView<String> getListView() {
            return listView;
        }
        public void setListView(ListView<String> listView) {
            this.listView = listView;
        }
        
        public void updateListView() {
            System.out.println("updateListView method called");
            if (dataModel != null && listView != null) {
                ObservableList<String> items = dataModel.getLists();
                System.out.println("Items in DataModel: " + items);
                listView.setItems(items);
                System.out.println("ListView items set: " + listView.getItems());

            }  else {
                System.out.println("DataModel or ListView is null. Unable to update the ListView.");
            }
        }
        


        public MyListEducationController() {
            dataModel = DataModel.getInstance(); 
        }

        public void addItemToListView(String item) {
            if (listView != null) {
                listView.getItems().add(item);
            }
        }
        
        public void setMyListScene(Scene myListScene) {
            this.myListScene = myListScene;
        }


        public void setDataModel(DataModel dataModel) {
            this.dataModel = dataModel; 

        }
        
        
        @FXML
        public void navigateToHomeEducationPage(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Home26_Education.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();

            MainController eduController = loader.getController();
            Scene eduScene = new Scene(root);

            Stage stage = (Stage) homeButton.getScene().getWindow();
            if (stage != null) {
                stage.setScene(eduScene);
            }
        }
        
        @FXML
        public void navigateToMyListEdu(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MyList_Education.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();

            MyListEducationController myListController = loader.getController();

            myListController.setDataModel(DataModel.getInstance());
            
            Scene myListScene = new Scene(root);
            myListController.setMyListScene(myListScene); 
            
            

            
            Stage stage = (Stage) eduDoneList.getScene().getWindow();
            if (stage != null) {
                stage.setScene(myListScene);
            }

            
        }
        public void navigateToProfilePage(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Profile.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();

            MainController educationController = loader.getController();
            Scene ProfileScene = new Scene(root);
            
            Stage stage = (Stage) profileButton.getScene().getWindow();
            System.out.println("Profile page");
            root =  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Profile.fxml"));
            stage.setScene(ProfileScene);
            
            
        }
        
        @FXML
        public void navigateToAddListPage(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("addList.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();

            AddListController addListController = loader.getController();

            DataModel dataModel = DataModel.getInstance();
            addListController.initialize(dataModel, this); 

            addListController.setMyListScene((Scene) addListButton.getScene());

            Scene addListScene = new Scene(root);
            
            Stage stage = (Stage) addListButton.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.setScene(addListScene);
            
        }

}
```

[DataModel Class]

```
package application;


import javafx.collections.FXCollections;

import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class DataModel {
    private static DataModel instance;

    private final ObservableList<String> lists;
    
    public DataModel() {
        lists = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        
    }
    public static DataModel getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DataModel();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    
    public ObservableList<String> getLists() {
        return lists;
    }
    
    public void addList(String title) {
        if (title != null && !title.isEmpty()) {
            lists.add(title);
        }
    }


    public static void setInstance(DataModel instance) {
        DataModel.instance = instance;
    }




}
```

[AddListController Class]

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AddListController{
    @FXML
    private TextField addEduTitle;
    @FXML
    private Button eduDoneList;
    @FXML
    private Button homeButton;
    @FXML
    private Button profileButton;
    @FXML
    private Button collabButton;
    @FXML
    private Button lockButton;
    
    private Scene myListScene;
    


    @FXML
    private MyListEducationController myListController;

    private DataModel dataModel; 
    
    public void setMyListEducationController(MyListEducationController myListController) {
        this.myListController = myListController;
    }
    public void setMyListScene(Scene scene) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.myListScene = scene;
    }
  
    public void initialize(DataModel dataModel, MyListEducationController myListController) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.dataModel = dataModel;
        this.myListController = myListController;

        addEduTitle.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                try {
                    handleAddListButton(new ActionEvent());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
        });
    }

    
    

    public String getTextFieldText() {
        return addEduTitle.getText();
    }
    


    public void setDataModel(DataModel dataModel) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.dataModel = dataModel;
    }
    public void setMainController(MainController mainController) {
    }
    
    @FXML
    public void navigateToHomeEducationPage(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Home26_Education.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();

        MainController eduController = loader.getController();
        Scene eduScene = new Scene(root);

        Stage stage = (Stage) homeButton.getScene().getWindow();
        if (stage != null) {
            stage.setScene(eduScene);
        }
      }
      
    
    public void navigateToProfilePage(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Profile.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();

        MainController educationController = loader.getController();
        Scene ProfileScene = new Scene(root);
        
        Stage stage = (Stage) profileButton.getScene().getWindow();
        System.out.println("Profile page");
        root =  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Profile.fxml"));
        stage.setScene(ProfileScene);
        
        
    }
    public void navigateToCollabPage(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Collaborate_Edu.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();

        MainController collabController = loader.getController();
        Scene collabChoice = new Scene(root);
        
        Stage stage = (Stage) collabButton.getScene().getWindow();
        System.out.println("Collaboration page");
        root =  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Collaborate_Edu.fxml"));
        stage.setScene(collabChoice);
        
        
    }
    
    public void navigateToCollabSetPass(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MyList_SetPass.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();

        MainController lockController = loader.getController();
        Scene lockScene = new Scene(root);
        
        Stage stage = (Stage) lockButton.getScene().getWindow();
        System.out.println("Lock Set Pass page");
        root =  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MyList_SetPass.fxml"));
        stage.setScene(lockScene);
        
    }

    
    @FXML
    private void handleAddListButton(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {
         String title = addEduTitle.getText();

            
            System.out.println("handleAddListButton clicked");
            System.out.println("Title: " + title);
           
            if (dataModel != null) {
                if (!title.isEmpty()) {
                    dataModel.addList(title); 
                    System.out.println("DataModel contents: " + dataModel.getLists());
                    myListController.updateListView(); 
                    addEduTitle.clear();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error: Title is empty.");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: DataModel is null.");
            }
    

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MyList_Education.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            
            MyListEducationController myListController = loader.getController();
            Scene myListScene = new Scene(root);
            myListController.setMyListScene(myListScene);
            
            Stage stage = (Stage) eduDoneList.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.setScene(myListScene);

    
        }


}
```

My MyList_Education.fxml file with the ListView as listView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Line?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="root" maxHeight="579.0" maxWidth="288.0" minHeight="579.0" minWidth="288.0" prefHeight="579.0" prefWidth="288.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FFF9FC" styleClass="scene2" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MyListEducationController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="15.0" layoutY="66.0" prefHeight="485.0" prefWidth="255.0" style="-fx-background-color: #F9DBE9; -fx-background-radius: 10;">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="11.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Education" textFill="#3c004b">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="39.0" layoutY="117.0" textFill="#3c004b">
               <font>
                  <Font size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Line endX="108.33334350585938" fill="#360045" layoutX="148.0" layoutY="103.0" startX="-107.99998474121094" stroke="#3c004b70" strokeWidth="2.0" style="-fx-background-color: rgba(60, 0, 75, 0.15);" />
            <Line endX="108.33334350585938" fill="#360045" layoutX="148.0" layoutY="156.0" startX="-107.99998474121094" stroke="#3c004b70" strokeWidth="2.0" style="-fx-background-color: rgba(60, 0, 75, 0.15);" />
            <RadioButton fx:id="eduList1Button" layoutX="16.0" layoutY="67.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="225.0" text="Final Exam Business Application Development" textFill="#3c004b" />
            <RadioButton layoutX="16.0" layoutY="119.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="225.0" style="-fx-background-color: #F9DBE9;" text="Mockup" textFill="#3c004b" />
            <Button fx:id="addListButton" contentDisplay="TOP" graphicTextGap="0.0" layoutX="215.0" layoutY="413.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#navigateToAddListPage" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="25.0" style="-fx-background-color: #F9DBE9;" textFill="#676769">
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets />
               </opaqueInsets>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="-10.0" />
               </padding>
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="32.0" fitWidth="25.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" style="-fx-background-color: #F9DBE9;">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../../../Downloads/myListImages/myList_page/AddListButton.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <ListView fx:id="listView" layoutX="29.0" layoutY="182.0" pickOnBounds="false" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-text-fill: #3c004b;" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <ImageView fitHeight="34.0" fitWidth="288.0" layoutY="-2.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../Downloads/statusBar_myList.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Label layoutX="39.0" layoutY="35.0" text="MyList" textFill="#3c004b">
         <font>
            <Font size="16.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="35.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FFF9FC;" text="&lt;" textFill="#380047" />
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" layoutY="531.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="288.0" spacing="50.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="8.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="homeButton" contentDisplay="TOP" graphicTextGap="0.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#navigateToHomeEducationPage" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="51.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" text="Home" textFill="#3c004b">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="22.0" fitWidth="24.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../../../eclipse/myListGUIImages/NavigationPanel_Home.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets />
               </opaqueInsets>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="-10.0" />
               </padding>
            </Button>
            <Button contentDisplay="TOP" graphicTextGap="0.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="51.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" text="MyList" textFill="#676769">
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets />
               </opaqueInsets>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="-10.0" />
               </padding>
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="22.0" fitWidth="24.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../../../eclipse/myListGUIImages/myListIcon.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="profileButton" contentDisplay="TOP" graphicTextGap="0.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#navigateToProfilePage" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="51.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" text="Profile" textFill="#676769">
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets />
               </opaqueInsets>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="-10.0" />
               </padding>
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="22.0" fitWidth="24.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../../../eclipse/myListGUIImages/ProfileIcon.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="5.0" />
         </padding>
      </HBox>
      <Line endX="194.0" endY="623.0" layoutX="94.0" layoutY="-92.0" startX="-94.00000762939453" startY="623.0" stroke="#fbebff" strokeWidth="4.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

How do I get the items to show on my ListView in my MyList_Education.fxml?

Comment: You should never have a public setter method  like `setListView` to set the value of an @FXML member that has been initialized by the FXMLLoader.  You may have other issues in your code.